# What is the limit on number of columns in Oracle 10G and Derby Databases

Tags: oracle, derby

Until recently I thought limit on number of columns in Oracle DB was 255. But turns out the limit is 1000. Can someone confirm this?

Also I was trying to find if there is any similar limit on number of columns in Derby DB, particularly embedded derby java DB

Comment: I saw now that you did not select accepted answer for any of the questions you asked. It would be helpful to others if you show that you got good answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's link to Oracle documentation: [Logical Database Limits](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm).
Excerpt:

```
Per table                           1000 columns maximum
Per index (or clustered index)        32 columns maximum
Per bitmapped index                   30 columns maximum
```

---

Here's link to Derby documentation: [A Derby Database](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop13.html)
Excerpt:

```
columns per table   1,012
```

Comment: Just for info, if you have more than 255 columns, the row will get stored in up to four 'row pieces'

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CNCPT1129

Comment: Derby 10.13 version (latest), it seems the maximum number of columns limitation is still there: https://fossies.org/linux/misc/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin.tar.gz/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin/docs/html/ref/rrefdbmlimits.html